# Trouble installing HP AMD Radeon™ HD 7570 1GB Drivers ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, radeon, gpu-driver

I've just physically installed a second hand HP AMD Radeon™ HD 7570 1GB on my 2011 HP Pavilion p7-1047c Desktop PC.

Im running:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

So I have downloaded the drivers here -> https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-7000-series/amd-radeon-hd-7570

when i try and install them i get an issue with `Package fglrx-core is not installed.` So then I try to install it manually

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package fglrx-core is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'fglrx-core' has no installation candidate
```

I did a bit of googling and enabled all my repositories

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190210)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main universe restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

still no luck:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package fglrx-core is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'fglrx-core' has no installation candidate
```

not sure how to proceed from here? Also a thing to not is once I did physically install the new Radeon card, the display didnt load anything it was just a black screen. I had to physically remove the card to try the above steps. Does the card need to be physically installed for me to install the drivers?

Comment: There are no proprietary drivers now for your distro and card. Do not try to install, just use the already installed open-source drivers.

Comment: Thanks thought that might be the case. I could probably go to am earlier version of Ubuntu. I also think it might a computability issue with the motherboard and the GPU as I installed windows 7 and the drivers and it still black screened. Updated bios, ran in safe mode and checked boot logs but nothing obvious. Abandoning ship as the GPU cost $20